# In Maven, what is the convention for including a resource from another project

Tags: maven

I am very new to Maven (one week) I have a project which is a subproject of many other parents and grandparent projects.  In  I need to  an XML file from a cousin project to the one I am in.

Is there a convention for doing this?  Can I just do.
${project.basedir}../../../other_project/src/main/resources

Seems a little like a kludge to me.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no convention cause you shouldn't do that. Furthermore if you are in the situation you need to think about it you should think about your application...Apart from that are those project related within a multi module project?

Comment: This project is millions of lines.  It has been in dev for over a decade....it is a multi module project.  I was tasked with getting one module to use resources in another module far removed.

Comment: If you have resources that means the resources will be packaged into the resulting jar file which means you can access that jar file and within the resources via the classpath...so in your other project just get the resources via classpath...no need to access via such weird constructions...

Comment: I think I mentioned above :)  I've been doing Java, Maven a week now.  So you will have to get the crayons out for me.  classpath?  It is a WSDL xml file so I don't know if it will be in the JAR or not....(like I said I am very very new to this Java thing)

Comment: In particular if you have a WSDL file this should belong in a separate module which contains the WSDL file and the code which will be generated from it...afterwards use the resulting JAR file...

Comment: Add the artifact as a dependency like all other dependencies

Comment: The reason you are not receiving any answers to your question is because you have not described how or when your project is using the resource from the other project. For example, do you need it while building your project, testing your project or running your project? This answer has an enormous impact on what you need to do.

Comment: If you need access to this file at runtime then you should do as @bish suggested and add the other project as a dependency to your project then access the file relative to your project's classpath. Search Stackoverflow for how to load a file from the classpath.

Comment: If you need access to this file at build time (e.g., you are generating Java classes from an XSD or WSDL file) then most tools allow you to specify a URL instead of a file path. You can then use a URL to the committed file in your source code repository instead of trying to reference it through a relative URL. Most repositories (e.g., SVN and Git) provide fully qualified URLs to any file in the repository.

Comment: If you only need access to this file while testing your project then the answer depends on what you are trying to do in your tests (i.e., is it a runtime or compile-time dependency). In this case, choose the best answer from my previous comments.